# Problem with public paths in different folders for webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I'm currently trying to start using webpack on my project. I have some .html in my root, and I need some other .html inside a folder (in my case, I'm trying to get some localhost/checkout/checkout.html running), but I'm running into a problem with paths. My current build folder looks like this:

```
dist
┣ checkout
┃ ┣ checkout.1250022740c1f2b813b8.bundle.js
┃ ┣ checkout.1250022740c1f2b813b8.bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
┃ ┣ checkout.css
┃ ┗ checkout.html
┣ index.b5619d26d74cdeec0170.bundle.js
┣ index.b5619d26d74cdeec0170.bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
┣ index.css
┣ index.html
┣ runtime.2c3d0415a90a938674ee.bundle.js
```

Basically, I have 2 pages (index, checkout), with checkout being inside a 'checkout' folder. For that, I'm following using these 2 entry points:

```
index: src/index.js, 
checkout/checkout: src/checkout/checkout.js
```

However, I'm running into some trouble on the checkout.html paths, which is importing

```
./checkout/checkout.css 
./runtime.bundle.js 
./checkout/checkout.bundle.js
```

when the right paths would be

```
../checkout/checkout.css 
../runtime.bundle.js 
../checkout/checkout.bundle.js
```

(basically one folder up). I can change my output.publicPath from './' to '../', but then it would break the paths of the index.html instead

Is there anyway I can solve this?